# Replacing string with "\" character in java

Tags: java, regex

I am matching a pattern which is a string "test" in sentence "you are test" and replace it with "test\".

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("test", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("you are test");
while (matcher.find()) {
matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "test\"));
            }
matcher.appendTail(sb);
replacementString = sb.toString();
```

The issue is in the statement `matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "test\"));` where "\" is considered as special character and replacement is not performed.

Please share your thoughts on how overcome this scenario and how to replace with a "\" in the string.

Comment: try following?
matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "<test\\>"));

Answer (score 6):

To put a `\` in a string literal in java, you have to escape it as `\\`.

But it's a little more complicated. See the javadoc :

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated
>   as references to captured subsequences as described above, and
>   backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement
>   string.

So you have to double-escape :

```
matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "test\\\\"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using all those lines of code, when one line will do the same thing:

```
String s = input.replaceAll("test", "$0\\\\");
```

Note the use of `$0` to back-reference the whole match, and the double-double backslash to create a literal regex backslash.